# Speed up Rendering of Feature Layer Using ArcGIS JavaScript API 4.0

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Are there any tricks to speed up the rendering of a feature layer in the ArcGIS JavaScript API?  Currently one of the layers I am using [is:](http://services3.arcgis.com/HVjI8GKrRtjcQ4Ry/arcgis/rest/services/State_Models/FeatureServer/0)

This takes about 10 seconds to draw but I have used [this](https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/3) layer which draws much faster: 
Is it just a function of the speed of the ESRI server I am using compared to the "sampleserver6" which the other layer is using?

Comment: The only time I experience noticeable difference in speed is with large polygons. 30K + short lines or points are no problem.

Comment: Do you mean over 30,000 polygons?  I only have 50 and it is very slow.  Would smoothing the polygons before publishing the feature layer have any effect?

Comment: No just the opposite. I have point layers with many features that are faster than a layer with maybe 50 polygons but they are large with (sometimes) complex shapes. I don't really know if it has something to do with needing to show only part of the polygon (when zoomed in) or what, but they are slower to display. I'm not sure about smoothing. Hopefully someone with some inside knowledge, can shed some light on this.

Comment: Have you tried playing with the maximum offset settings? That sometimes helps with rendering.

Comment: Where do I make those changes?

Comment: I googled after @npeihl 's comment and found this blog link. https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/06/13/feature-layers-can-generalize-geometries-on-the-fly/

Answer (score 2):

As of 2018, there is a [new sample that shows and explains some FeatureLayer Performance Improvements](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/layers-featurelayer-webgl/index.html) for version 4.6.